# Why App name change is not reflected in iOS 7 Notification centre?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, apple-push-notifications

I have changed the App name (Bundle Display name, Product Name and also in iTunes Connect) for my iOS 7 app (which is been in App store for long time) in iTunes connect while updating my new version. Now the app is been approved and name changes are reflected everywhere except in iOS 7 notification centre. (But in iOS 6 notification centre it is changed)

In iOS 7 notification centre , list of notifications for my App has new name , but the Title is not changed.

How to change the title Name in notification Centre ?

Any help please?

Comment: I think you have to change the name on your certificates and please your project name.

Comment: go to your xCode project.  Targets > Info > Bundle name also Targets > Info > Bundle display name

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this issue and it has a very simple solution. This problem is related to iOS 7 Push Notifications.

> Just **RESTART THE DEVICE** and the app name will be reflected in the
>   notification center as desired. :)